# How to get all of the meshes that are attached to an armature via Python?

Tags: python, mesh, armature

I know that I can get all of the meshes in a scene by doing this:

```
 for obj in bpy.data.objects:
     if obj.type == 'MESH':
          # Do stuff
```

But let’s say I have an armature named `rig` in the scene, and I have several meshes that have been parented to that armature and have been weighted.

How can I loop through all of the meshes in a scene that are attached to a specific armature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can loop through all objects and check if they are parented to the armature.

```
rig = bpy.data.objects['rig']
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if obj.parent == rig:
        # Do stuff
        pass
```

If some objects are only connected via the armature modifier, simply check that the `rig` is the [`object`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ArmatureModifier.html#bpy.types.ArmatureModifier.object) of the armature modifier.

```
rig = bpy.data.objects['rig']
for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if (obj.type == 'MESH' and
        rig in [m.object for m in obj.modifiers if m.type == 'ARMATURE']
        ):
        # Do stuff
        pass
```

Comment: Perfect! I ended up using your second suggestion so it works in all cases:

    rig = bpy.data.objects['rig']
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH':
            for modifier in obj.modifiers:
                if (modifier.type == 'ARMATURE'):
                    if modifier.object == rig:
                       # Do stuff

Comment: Cool, I added your suggestion to the answer in a variant.

Comment: @FahadHasanPathik  Also a good example use case for any _eg_ `and any(m.object is rig for m in obj.modifiers if m.type == 'ARMATURE')`